# Creating a div element on the server side using C#

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I am trying to create divs dynamically in a view page of an asp.net mvc project. This is the pseudo code:

```
<%
        foreach (element in Model)
        {
           create the html div element with Div.id = Model.id 
        }
    %>
```

I looked in the system.web.mvc.htmlhelper object. It provides support for a lot of html elements but not a div. Any Hints ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such helper for div. But, you can create your own HTML helper for it.

or simply you can go ahead and create divs in view page as

```
<%
        foreach (element in Model)
        {
           %>
          <div id="<%:element.id%>">
                .. some html..
           </div>     
      <%}
    %>
```